# What is the Query to add in robots.txt for blocking URLs has some special characters?

Tags: google-search-console, web-crawlers, robots.txt, crawl-errors, technical-seo

I was going through the Google Search Console pages issues and one of the issue reason is "Alternate page with proper canonical tag" and this has some URLs which look like below

```
example.com/abc/?hstc_sdb.sdhjb16573.328y......and so on
example.com/abc/?utm_term........and son on
example.com/abc/?job... and so on
example.com/abc/?amp... and so on
example.com/abc/?hs... and so on
```

and many more like this, however, i am not sure from where these are coming so i though of adding queries in robots.txt for disallowing some attributes and to avoid these types of pages to be crawled by search engines (My 1st question if this is the right and good approach)

2nd questions is what can be the exact queries to be added in robots.txt for above mentioned URLs, are the below one will solve the purpose?

```
Disallow: /?amp
Disallow: /?hs
Disallow: /?__hstc
Disallow: /?job
Disallow: /?utm
```

if not what are the right queries?

Its a wordpress website

Answer (score 1):

To answer your second question:

If the URLs are within a sub-folder like your example (example.com/**abc**/?amp) the following would work:

```
Disallow: /abc/
```

This follows Google's recommendations on [URL matching based on path values](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/robots/robots_txt).

If there's no subdirectory, you will need to implement a wildcard, such as:

```
Disallow: /?*
```

However, anything starting with question mark would be ignored, which perhaps isn't ideal.

Now, is this the correct approach? It's certainly going to help remove them from Google. I'd personally investigate why those URLs are appearing and try to find the cause, but this would be an appropriate interim fix.